# How to search document by date in MongoDB 3.3 using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I'm wondering if anyone can help me search a collection in MongoDB using date as a parameter. I have stored a java.sql.Date object in my collection and there are no issues with puts/finds. The problem arises when I search using **date** as a parameter. When I do his I get an empty result.

Java code :

```
// Boiler plate
MongoClient client = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("my-database");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("my-collection")

// This returns nothing
java.sql.Date date = someFunctionToSetDate();
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(new Document("date",date)).iterator();
```

Anyone have any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

can you try with java.util.date instead of java.sql.date.

this is what i tried in my local and it works

```
package com.mongo.examples;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.bson.BsonDocument;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class MongoDateTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("testdates");

        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("dts");
        collection.drop();
        List<Document> insertList = new ArrayList<Document>();
        Date date = new Date();
        Document document = new Document().
                append("_id", 20).append("date",date);
        insertList.add(document);
        collection.insertMany(insertList);
        System.out.println(collection.count());
        MongoCursor<Document> doc = collection.find(new Document("date", date)).iterator();
        System.out.println(doc.next().getDate("date"));
    }
}
```

output :

```
1
Wed Aug 24 12:34:20 PDT 2016
```

Comment: @T-Pane did this help ?

Comment: no still not working. So I am converting from java.sql.Date to java.util.Date when doing an insert and vice versa when on find. Do you know what format mongoDB stores dates in?

Comment: Did u see my sample example ?

Comment: Yeah I just changed everything to java.util.Date and it works now. Thanks @user641887